# List of used Tables/View in Linq DBML file diagram

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq, linq-to-sql

Visual Studio 2010 show dbml file of linq to sql mapping as a class diagram. Is there a way to view all mapped tables/views as a list?? I have a lot of tables and for view if a table already is mapped have to find it in a too big graphic diagram!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you open the designer and view the Properties window (press F4) there's a combo box at the top of the Properties window. This box contains all the objects that are on the designer - the entities (tables and views), the associations (the foreign keys and joins), and the datacontext itself.

If you select an item from the combo box, the corresponding item will be selected on the designer.

Comment: Any way to collect all tables, stored procedures, views in one text list?

Comment: @Bomberlt they all exist in the generated `cs` file; if you head in there you could extract them. But there's no 'easy' way to achieve this.

Comment: Wrote a little snippet for LINQPad for getting all that :) http://pastebin.com/GsNRPTbc